# Mediawiki Hiding extra URL parameter

Tags: php, url, mediawiki

I have a Mediawiki extension that requires a "dbid" parameter in the URL to work.
ULRs for normal pages are in /w/Main_Page format, and where the extension is supposed to be launched, /w/Page?dbid=1234.
Now, I have been trying to hide dbid= with a / (slash).
I tried setting up htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?title=$1&dbid=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

But it only works as long as I don't enable short URLs in the wiki ($wgArticlePath = "{$wgScriptPath}/$1";). If I do so, wiki keeps thinking "Page/1234" is the title.
I have found this
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Entry_point_routing
but I have no idea how to use it.

I made a simple extension with just

```
$wgHooks['WebRequestPathInfoRouter'][] = 'ePathRouter';
function ePathRouter( $router ) {
 $router->addStrict( "/Page/100650030", array( 'title' => 'Main_Page' ) );
 return true;
}
```

to just test if it's going to redirect "/Page/100650030" to the "Main_Page" but it doesn't work at all.

So my question is, how do I use this hook?

Answer (score 1):

After I posted this question, I managed to figure it out.

Like I mentioned before, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Entry_point_routing is the way to go.

I made an extension that contains only:

```
$wgHooks['WebRequestPathInfoRouter'][] = 'MyExtensionURLRouter';
function MyExtensionURLRouter( $router ) {
  $router->add( 'w/Page/$1', array( 'title' => 'Page', 'dbid' => '$1' ) );
  return true;
}
```

With just this, when you try to access a page called "Page/100", you will, in fact, be presented with the content of a page called, "Page", and the number/text/whatever after the slash will be the value for the parameter "dbid".

You have to remember to change the 'w/Page/$1'.
If your wiki has URLs like https://mywiki.wiki/w/Main_Page, you have to start it with "w/", if your URLs are https://mywiki.wiki/Main_Page, you have to start with "Page/" (or any other page obviously).

For htaccess, stick to the "default" one for short URLs. In my case,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

and short URLs settings in LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
$wgArticlePath = "{$wgScriptPath}/$1";
```